# How to Condition the two Date and time from database into label current date and time

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How to compare the date from MS Access Column "Time" in Time in my label form.
heres my code

```
Dim sql = "Select CompanyCode From LAPostingCoCode where CompanyCode = '" + ComboBox1.text"' AND User = '" & txtuser.text & "' AND Time = '" & LblTime.text & "'"

Using Olecon As New OleDbConnection(cons)
    Using command as new OleDbDCommand(sql,olecon)
        Using adapter as New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
            Dim Table As New DataTable()
            adapter.Fill(table)

            If (table.Rows.Count > 0 ) Then
                btnSave.Enabled = false
            Else
                btnSave.Enabled = true
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End using
```

I want to compare the date and time from database Column into my Form Label Current Date and Time. So that if the date and time in the database is 02-02-18 4:42:01, and in my label is 02-02-18 05:02:31. the button save will be enabled = true because the time is almost 5pm. when 4:42:01 is equal into time label. the save button still enabled = false.

I am using vb.net and MS access. help me please. thanks

Comment: Please be sure to post your code properly. You cut the last double-quote of your `String` and so everything after that was miscoloured and you also didn't include any indenting, thus making the code harder to read. Posting easy-to-read code in order to help us help you is not much to ask.

Comment: You don't need to nest `Using` statements like that unless want code between them.  You can create multiple objects with a single `Using` statement and separate them with commas, e.g. `Using Olecon As New OleDbConnection(cons), command as new OleDbDCommand(sql,olecon), adapter as New OleDbDataAdapter(command)`. Also, creating the `OleDbCommand` object here is pointless because you can just create an `OleDbDataAdapter` directly with a `String` query and a connection object.  The command is created internally.

Comment: You really ought to learn how to use [parameters in ADO.NET](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) now to save yourself potentially significant issues down the track.

Comment: Forget the `Label`. `Labels` are for displaying data to the user, not data storage. You don't compare anything with a `Label`.  If you want to store a date and time for later use then use a `DateTime` variable.  Note that `Date` is the same thing as `DateTime`, just as `Integer` is the same as `Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

The code will let you compare two dates , please modify the code as required :

```
 'Assuming your date is formatted as : dd/mm/yyyy

 Dim date1 = DateTime.Parse("02/05/2018")

 Dim date2 = DateTime.Parse("03/07/2018")

 If date1.Date >date2.Date Then

 End if
```

Now for example , for example , you want to compare dateTime column of your table with your `label`'s date(i mean .text),do this "

```
 Dim dt1 = DateTime.Parse(yourDataTable(0)(3))  'Here 0 is the row count and 3 is the column count

'Follow the first code block's code now :)
```

**Suggestion**: Please don't use direct values in your `Select` statement as it opens doors to Sql-Injection.

[Read more about SQL-Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Rather,pass parameters and use your `SqlCommand` to pass values :

```
 Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("Select CompanyCode From LAPostingCoCode where CompanyCode = @code",connection)

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@code",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.text
```

And please use `Parameter.Add` method , most people use `AddWithValue` which not the proper way.Because at points, it may not cause errors/may not conflict with data but in most cases it'll corrupt the data.The reason is that , it infers the database type to query parameter.

[Read more here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Microsoft will be thrilled to know that one of their standard ADO.net methods will " in most cases it'll corrupt the data." .AddWithValue may slow down queries or cause an error if the database cannot convert the supplied value to the correct datatype but it will not corrupt the data.